# Open ERP does not trigger related Business via XmlRPC webservice call

Tags: odoo, xml-rpc

We use openerp 6. When i execute an action from openERP user interface , for example Confirm Order , some other business related to that action execute too ,for example create Picking List.

But when i do same action via XmlRpc these business does not execute.
When i update Sales Order to Confirm Order state by XmlRpc no Picking List create.
I want to know if calling XmlRpc cause related business behind one model or workflow to execute or not.

Comment: Could you add a simple example of a xmlrpc call with a description what it should do?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you directly changing the state to confirmed ? If so this is the problem. Pushing the confirm button calls a method that does more than changing the state. I don't know if it's the same thing in OpenERP 6 though, I began developping on Odoo V8.

It would be something like this in Python (if you follow this guide https://www.odoo.com/documentation/8.0/api_integration.html) :

```
models.execute_kw(db, uid, password,
     'sale.order', 'confirm_order',
     [sale_order_ids])
```

Or maybe you just have to call the workflow transition.

```
models.exec_workflow(
    db, uid, password, 'sale_order', 'order_confirm', sale_order_id)
```